# Extracting strings inside a list of strings

Tags: python, regex

I have a string which is a list of strings.

Like below:

```
a=   "['expert executive', 'internal committee period', 'report name', 'entry']"

type(a)
Out[23]:
str
```

Now if I want to extract all the inside strings and store it in a list I was using regular expression like below:

```
re.findall(r"\w+\s+\w+",a)

Out[24]:
['expert executive',
 'internal committee',
 'report name',
 'entry']
```

If you see it will only extract two words inside the string and if a string is more than two characters it won't extract it as I have only two words in my pattern. How do I make it for any no. of words inside a string and it extracts all of that. Like output should be:

```
['expert executive',
     'internal committee period',
     'report name',
     'entry']
```

The no. of words inside a string in the list can be variable.

Comment: Probaly your actual string is `a= "['expert executive', 'internal committee period', 'report name', 'entry']"`. If yes, try [`ast.literal_eval(a)`](http://rextester.com/EPONK15097).

Comment: issue is that I need to add two such columns of pandas and combine it into one list. So i need to use a list comprehension and that makes it a list of lists if I use ast.literal_eval

Comment: _I have a string which is a list of strings_ Your example code is an actual list.  It's confusing when you say one thing but your code says something else.

Comment: no its not an actual list. If you see type it says str.

Comment: Please update the question with the list comprehension you have trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

This regular expression uses positive lookahead (`(?<=')`) and lookbehind (`(?=')`) to match the `'` character at beginning and end of each match, without including it in the resulting match:

```
>>> re.findall(r"(?<=')[\w\s]*(?=')",a)
['expert executive', 'internal committee period', 'report name', 'entry']
```